# Install mod_proxy to get ProxyPass to work

Tags: drivers, 10.04, apache2, proxy

I've been trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/faq:installation:apacheproxy), so that I could get the Citadel mail server to work alongside Apache, but I get an error when I try to restart Apache:

> Invalid command 'ProxyPass', ...

I was told in the Apache docs that this is from the `mod_proxy` module, but `apt-get install mod_proxy` gives `E: Couldn't find package mod_proxy`, and I was unable to find it on the big list on the Apache site.  What do I need to do to get the ProxyPass working in Ubuntu 10.04 TLS?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In the end I guessed that the module `proxy_http` in the `mods-enabled` directory might work, and used the command:

```
a2enmod proxy_http
```

My Proxy statements work now.